# A way of setting custom configuration properties that can be changed via power shell

Tags: development, powershell, configuration

I have a few custom settings for my feature that I am creating. I want a way to populate these values on install with some default values. However if needed an admin should be able to change the defaults via powershell. Is this possible? The settings would be at the web applciation level but could saved somewhere else if that would help.

Wictor has [Six ways to store settings in SharePoint](http://www.wictorwilen.se/Post/Six-ways-to-store-settings-in-SharePoint.aspx) would any of these meet my needs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually you can reach almost any SharePoint object from the PowerShell.

For example, [SPWebApplication.Properties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.administration.sppersistedobject.properties.aspx) can be modified using the following PowerShell code:

```
$web = Get-SPWeb http://localhost
$webApplication = $w.Site.WebApplication
$webApplication.Properties["xxx"] = "yyy"
$webApplication.Update()
```

Screenshot:

[image]

To set the default values, you can use C# code in Feature Receiver.

Please, note, that for activating WebApplication-scoped feature, as well as for accessing the *SPWebApplication.Properties* collection, you should have farm administrator permissions.

Answer (score 1):

I think what would work for you is the property bag. Since its accessible via .NET you can write powershell scripts to interact with them accordingly.

http://www.fivenumber.com/understanding-sharepoint-property-bag-settings/